# Kubernetes :: web interface to start a pod

Tags: html, kubernetes, automation

**Background:**

As a backoffice service for our insurance mathematicians, a daily cronjob runs a pod.
Inside the pod, fairly complex future simulations take place.
The pod has two containers, an application server and a db server.
The process has few variables which are fed into the pod.
This is done by configmaps and container env variables.
When the pod is ready after approx. 10 hours, it copies the resulting database to another database
and then it's done. It runs daily because market data changes daily. And we also daily check our new codebase.

Great value, high degree of standardisation, fully automated.
So far so good.
But it uses the same configuration every time it runs.

**Now what?**

Our mathematicians would like to be able to start the pod feeding their own configuration data into it.
For example on a webpage with configurable input data.

**Question:**

Is there an existing Kubernetes framework implementing this?
"Provide a webpage with configurable input fields which are transformed into configmaps and env variables starting the pod"?

Sure, not too difficult to write.
But we do cloud native computing also because we want to reuse solutions of general problems and not write it ourselves if possible.

Thanks for any hints in advance.

Answer (score 0):

They can start a Kubernetes Job for one time tasks. Apart from Google Cloud Console UI I'm not aware of an UI where you can configure fields for a config map. Maybe you can write a custom python script that launches these jobs.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/